# What is the proof that if subsets $gH$ have no common elements then $H$ must be a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In proving Lagrange's Theorem we're usually first showing that cosets have no common elements. I'm looking for the proof that if subsets $gH$ have no common elements, then $H$ must be a subgroup.

Comment: You mean if the sets of the form $g S$ have no elements in common then $S s^{-1}$ is a subgroup. Assume $S = H s$ with $H$ a subgroup, that $g_1S, g_2 S$ have an element in common but are no the same means $g_1h_1s=g_2h_2s, g_1 h_3s\in g_1 Hs,\not \in g_2 Hs$. Can you finish from there ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the claim is not true without assuming that $H$ contains the identity $e$, because any coset is a counter example.

Now let me prove:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H\subseteq G$ be a subset containing the identity element $e$. Suppose that for any two elements $g, g'\in G$, either $gH = g'H$ or $gH \cap g'H = \emptyset$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Proof: Let $h$ be any element of $H$. We have $e = h^{-1}h = ee \in h^{-1}H \cap eH$, hence $h^{-1}H = eH = H$. In particular, the element $h^{-1}e = h^{-1}$ is in $H$.

On the other hand, we have $h = he = eh \in hH \cap eH$, hence $hH = eH = H$. Thus for any $h'\in H$, we have $hh' \in H$.

This shows that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.